# generate QR code and merge in edited JPG file

Tags: php, image

My requirements are simple. There is a JPG file. Some text is introduced into it. QR code is generated and saved as png file. This PNG file is merged with JPG file. The JPG image that is output doesn't contain the QR code. I am wrong somewhere but I don't get where. Here are my codes:

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '64M');
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('certificate.jpg');
if ($jpg_image) {
    $text = $name;
    $textc = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 0, 0, 0);
    $font_path = '../images/CHOPS___.TTF';
    imagettftext($jpg_image, 42, 0, 300, 400, $textc, $font_path, $text);
    include('phpqrcode/qrlib.php');
    $tempDir = 'temp/';
    $fileName = 'tmp_'.md5($reg).'.png';
    $pngAbsoluteFilePath = $tempDir.$fileName;
    if (!file_exists($pngAbsoluteFilePath)) {
        QRcode::png($text, $pngAbsoluteFilePath);
        $qrcode = imagecreatefrompng($pngAbsoluteFilePath); 
        imagecopymerge($jpg_image, $qrcode, 10, 10, 0, 0, 100, 47, 75);
    }
    header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
    imagejpeg($jpg_image);
    imagedestroy($jpg_image);
```

Comment: Where you are wrong first of all, is in trying to pass off _"I am wrong somewhere"_ as a problem description to begin with.

Comment: @CBroe Sorry, I edited my query.

Comment: Well then the first thing to check would be whether `if (!file_exists($pngAbsoluteFilePath))` was actually true. We can't see what your `$reg` is here, but if that same value gets used multiple times(?), then you'd be creating the same temp file name as well.